# How to optimize title and description tags for blogspot search result (data: blog.searchQuery)?

Tags: blogger

I want to optimize the title tag and description for blogspot search results with  but it doesn't work. Below is the code I tried with the  tag.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'>
 <title><data:blog.pageTitle/> | Nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa</title>
 <meta content='Kết quả tìm kiếm về &quot;+ data:blog.searchQuery + &quot; tại nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa. Môi giới ký gửi nhà đất quận Gò Vấp và quận 12. name='description'/>
 <meta content='mua ban &quot;+ data:blog.searchQuery + &quot;,' name='keywords'/>
</b:if>
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data:blog.searchQuery` no longer works, use `data:view.search.query`

Also you have to use `expr` operator before tags content attribute and include a space before `+` operator with enclosing your text by quotes.

```
<b:if cond='data:view.search.query'>
 <title><data:blog.pageTitle/> | Nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa</title>
 <meta expr:content='"Kết quả tìm kiếm về " + data:view.search.query + " tại nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa. Môi giới ký gửi nhà đất quận Gò Vấp và quận 12."' name='description'/>
 <meta expr:content='"mua ban " + data:view.search.query + ","' name='keywords'/>
</b:if>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Thank you very much! I look forward to the answer from you

Comment: Description and keyword are not working bro, just show `" + data:view.search.query + "`

Comment: Oh, sorry i forget the expr operator before attributes. updated :)

Comment: `<title>Nhà Đất Sơn Nghĩa - Bán nhà gò vấp quận 12: Kết quả tìm kiếm về nha go vap gia 3 ty | Nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa</title>`
`<!--Unable to display topic button 'meta'.`

`The expression 'Kết quả tìm kiếm về " + data:view.search.query + " tại nhà đất Sơn Nghĩa. Môi giới ký gửi nhà đất quận Gò Vấp và quận 12.' is not valid.`
`-->`
`<!--Unable to display topic button 'meta'.`

`The expression 'mua ban " + data:view.search.query + ",' is not valid.`
-->`

Comment: Ok what about now after adding expr: operator

Comment: Hey men, Look like `expr` is not a problem.

Comment: Okey men, i'm following :D

Comment: The problem was in " " before and after your test try now.

Comment: OMG! You are the best @Bassam :D ! Yeah, It's working perfectly now bro! Thank you so much :D

Comment: Hey @Bassam can you help me looking for this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/q/58987013/12088833](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58987013/12088833)